# Writing to a bmp file in C

Tags: c, fwrite, bmp

I am having difficulties when writing to a bmp file.
Here is the code where the matrix is allocated:

```
  // Dynamically allocate matrix for the bitmap and 
  // while doing so, color it in blue.
  Pixel **bmp_matrix = (Pixel**)malloc(config.resolution_height_ * 
                                       sizeof(Pixel*));
  if (bmp_matrix == NULL)
  {
    printf("error: out of memory\n");
    return MEMORY_ERROR;
  }
  int rows = 0;
  for(; rows < config.resolution_height_; rows++)
  {
    bmp_matrix[rows] = (Pixel*)malloc(config.resolution_width_ * 
                                      sizeof(Pixel));
    if (bmp_matrix[rows] == NULL)
    {
      while(--rows >= 0)
        free(bmp_matrix[rows]);
      free(bmp_matrix);
      printf("error: out of memory\n");
      return MEMORY_ERROR;
    }
    int columns = 0;
    for(; columns < config.resolution_width_; columns++)
      {
        bmp_matrix[rows][columns].red_ = 175;
        bmp_matrix[rows][columns].green_ = 175;
        bmp_matrix[rows][columns].blue_ = 255;
      }
  }
```

Here is the code for writing the pixels:

```
int height, width, pad_iterator;
  for(height = info_header.height_ - 1; height >= 0; height--)
  {
    // for(width = 0; width < info_header.width_; width++)
    //   fwrite(&bmp_matrix[height][width], sizeof(Pixel), 1, bitmap_file);
    fwrite(&bmp_matrix[height], sizeof(Pixel), info_header.width_, bitmap_file);
    for(pad_iterator = 0; pad_iterator < pad_length; pad_iterator++)
      fwrite(&pad, sizeof(Byte), 1, bitmap_file);
  }
```

Now, when I use the `for` loop which is commented, everything works perfectly. The resulting image is OK.
However, I am trying to substitute it with a single `fwrite` so the program would not have to iterate the loop.
In this case the resulting image is completely wrong.

Any help?

Comment: What type is `bmp_matrix`? Is it `Pixel[][]`?

Comment: @David Schwartz It does not write the same byte over and over...
1. In case when the second for loop is used it writes separately each character in line after line. Notice that the 2 dimensional array is iterated with [height][width]...

2. in case when the for loop is not used, it should just write complete lines.

Comment: What does your unrolled code look like?

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe I think we're supposed to be comparing the two commented out lines of code to the line below them.

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe I am not quite sure what do you mean with unrolled code...

Comment: @David Schwartz Yes, `bmp_matrix` is of type `Pixel[][]`

Comment: How is `bmp_matrix` declared?

Comment: You should try `fwrite(&bmp_matrix[height][0], sizeof(Pixel), info_header.width_, bitmap_file);` (note the `[0]`). It normally does the same as your commented loop.

Comment: I second @Serge. Since the width of the image is dynamic --  is it possible that bmp_matrix is actually a one dimensional array of Pixel pointers, each pointing to width Pixels which are dynamically allocated? Show more code, especially all relevant declarations and initializations. Alternatively, write `bmp_matrix[height]`(without the address op).

Comment: I did what @Serge suggested and it seems to work. Actually now it makes sense. I was pointing to a wrong memory address. At least as I see it... Following is equal:
`&bmp_matrix[height][0] == &(*(bmp_matrix[height])) `

Thanks @Serge !

Comment: And `&(*(bmp_matrix[height]))` is equivalent to `bmp_matrix[height]` since the "address of operator" `&` is an inverse of the "dereference operator" `*`. The operations cancel each other out. `bmp_matrix[height]` is a simple value, as if bmp_matrix was just a one dimensional int array. The value is an address though, namely the address of the first `Pixel` in the memory block obtained by `malloc`. Writing dereference/reference pairs around it doesn't add any value (and will not result in any code anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second try is incorrect.

In your commented write (`fwrite(&bmp_matrix[height][width], sizeof(Pixel), 1, bitmap_file);`), you use one pixel at address `&bmp_matrix[height][width]` which is correct.

But in `fwrite(&bmp_matrix[height], sizeof(Pixel), info_header.width_, bitmap_file);`, you write bytes from the address `&bmp_matrix[height]` ... which may be different things depending on the actual declaration of `bmp_matrix`

You should use either `&bmp_matrix[height][0]` ie. the address of first pixel in a row or equivently (as suggested by Peter Schneider) `bmp_matrix[height]` (without the `&`) both giving a correct address.